# Pre-1948 Haredi view on political Zionism and how it developed

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, eretz-yisrael, zionism, israel

Are there any readings discussing  the Haredi (Hasidic, orthodox non-Mizrachi) stance on political Zionism prior to the establishment of the State of Israel?

Did it change with the establishment of the state? If so, in what way?

Any recommended readings on the topic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haredim_and_Zionism useful

Comment: דברי יואל from the Satmar rebbe

Comment: @kouty Wasn't that after 1948?

Comment: Herzl established the Zionist Movement in 1897, which was 9 years after R' Shimshon Raphael Hirsch's passing, but he (R' Hirsch) did write many things which would lead us to conclude he was opposed to Zionism. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12154/11486

Comment: @ezra yeeh.....

Comment: @kouty **Pre-1948** Haredi view on political Zionism and how it developed

Comment: Divrei Yoel @kouty was a continuation of the Satmar Rebbe's grandfather's(R' Moshe Teitelbaum ztz"l)view of Zionism which was way before 1948. They weren't alone in their views in that anti-zionism was the norm in almost all orthodox circles because the original zionists were vehemently anti-religious. Remember, Herzl offered to make Israel a catholic state in order to appease the pope; so long as the Jews had their own state...Modern zionism is based on heretic foundations.

Answer (score 2):

For one perspective on how an anti-Zionist changed perspectives 180 degrees and became a supporter, I would highly recommend [Eim HaBanim Semeicha](http://www.urimpublications.com/eim-habanim-semeichah-on-eretz-yisrael-redemption-and-unity.html) by R [Yissachar Shlomo Teichtal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yissachar_Shlomo_Teichtal)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eim_HaBanim_Semeicha)

> Teichtal grew up as a staunch anti-Zionist Chasid of the Munkatsher
>   Rebbe. However, during the Holocaust, Rabbi Teichtal changed his
>   position from the one he espoused in his youth. The physical product
>   of that introspection is the book, Eim HaBanim Semeicha, in which he
>   specifically retracts his previous viewpoints, and argues that the
>   true redemption can only come if the Jewish people unite and rebuild
>   the land of Israel. Many of his coreligionists viewed the book with
>   skepticism, some going so far as to ban Rabbi Teichtal from their
>   synagogues.
>
> In the book, Rabbi Teichtal strongly criticizes the Haredim for not
>   supporting the Zionist movement. When it was written, it was a
>   scathing criticism of the Jewish Orthodox establishment, and Agudat
>   Israel in particular.

The book is not quick or simple to read but it is an incredibly scholarly review of sources (most of it written from memory as the author was hiding from the Nazis with no access to his books).

See also [here](http://toratzion.com/books/eim-habanim-semeichah) for a summary and [here](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/805250/rabbi-moshe-lichtman/intro-to-eim-habanim-semeichah/) for an audio *shiur*.

Comment: Are you giving this a an example of "the Haredi... stance on political Zionism prior to the establishment of the State of Israel" or as an example of how that "change[d] with the establishment of the state"? If the former, you'd do well to mention that this stance is atypical rather than "the" stance; if the latter, note that the change you mentioned took place before Israel became a country.

Comment: Actually both as the book both criticizes the traditional haredi anti Zionist perspective and develops a new haredi pro Zionist perspective which has become more common now in so-called hardal (haredi dati leumi) circles. Agree R Teichtal change of mind came before the establishment of Israel though but still hope the answer will be of help to the OP

Comment: This doesn't represent everyone.

Comment: I am puzzled by the downvotes. Do downvoters disagree the book is a relevant source?, don't like the book?, don't like me? :->

Comment: @chachamNisan clear, it is one man's perspective, but a very relevant one for those trying to understand pre-war haredi perspectives on Zionism

Comment: @mbloch I disagree with the book being a relevant source. It does not represent the general "Haredi (Hasidic, orthodox non-Mizrachi)" view.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I understand, thanks for clarifying your view. But you will agree that it is rare to find one view in Judaism, 2 Jews 3 opinions. The book reflects one of these opinions.

Comment: @mbloch true, except that this is one opinion that is very well-known to be a minority opinion...

Comment: I downvoted. Don't get me wrong; I respect you and like you as a person(from my communications with you) because you're a nice, intelligent, and respectable person. It's just that I think the answer doesn't represent all those(or even most) of the people to which the question was directed to. No offense, intended. But(after a second look) I guess it does partially answer the question, so I will undo my vote.

Comment: @chachamNisan No problem, even if you downvoted, I was trying to understand - I like to be helpful and was trying to understand what the bug was. I also edited the answer to say this is "one". I might also be colored by the fact I was extremely impressed by the book: the scholarship of the author, his intellectual honesty, his command of sources by heart, etc. Might make a bit over enthusiastic

Comment: Is this book available anywhere online?

Comment: Where can this book be bought at a reasonable price? Any suggestions?

Comment: @ElShteiger it appears to be online [here](http://israel613.com/books/ERETZ_EM_HA_BANIM-ENG.pdf) (but I cannot say if it is legal) and available from Israel [here](http://toratzion.com/books/eim-habanim-semeichah) and [here](http://www.pomeranzbooks.com/Eim-Habanim-Semeicha-_179_p.html)

Answer (score 0):

please see Shu"t Avnei Nezer Yoreh Deah 454

Comment: Hi, could you explain or summarize? Thanks.

Comment: Rabbi Student does a great job of expressing stating and clarifying pre-war haredi perspectives on Zionism in english                                                
 (IIRC he summerizes the Avnei Nezer) https://www.scribd.com/doc/2896972/Religious-Zionism-Debate